# vsftp server returning 500 Illegal PORT command when tried to run raw ftp commands in telnet

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, telnet, nc

Currently, I am trying to run ftp commands from telnet client. I was successful with `USER`, `PASS`, `PASV`, `LIST` and when tried `PORT` vsftp server is throwing `500 Illegal PORT command`. I am following the syntax as specified in RFC 959

> DATA PORT (PORT)
>
> The argument is a HOST-PORT specification for the data port
>   to be used in data connection.  There are defaults for both
>   the user and server data ports, and under normal
>   circumstances this command and its reply are not needed.  If
>   this command is used, the argument is the concatenation of a
>   32-bit internet host address and a 16-bit TCP port address.
>   This address information is broken into 8-bit fields and the
>   value of each field is transmitted as a decimal number (in
>   character string representation).  The fields are separated
>   by commas.  A port command would be:
>
> PORT h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2
>
> where h1 is the high order 8 bits of the internet host
>   address.

I tried to check if it is a problem related to `vsftpd` configuration file using `ftp` command. It was working fine with passive mode turn off. So why is it throwing error when I run from telnet client ? Below I attach the screenshot of `telnet` session, and `nc` session where I am trying to listen for data connection.

[image]

Comment: asking for port 100, which is reserved as it is less than 2048, is a bad idea. What happens if you ask say "PORT 127,0,0,1,100,0" to ask for port 25600 ?

Comment: Yes it works fine ! Thanks. But here we are not asking, we are saying it to which port to connect and transfer data, So why should server be worried about connecting to the restricted ports of the client ?

Comment: Because using low level ports is probably a way to involve the server in some intrusion attempt. The developpers just prohibited it

Comment: @A.B That is an interesting answer ! So RFC wont put any constraints on the data-connection ports, its the developers that put.

Comment: yes: there: https://salsa.debian.org/mentors.debian.net-team/vsftpd/-/blob/debian/3.0.3-12/postlogin.c#L992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In olden days when the world was young, pterodactyls still flew in the sky, a computer that was able to connect to a IP network cost $100,000 (and those were real dollars) and  most of the system administrators of those machines knew each other on a first name basis, it was decided to partition the 65535 TCP ports (or is it 65536) into two groups and make the Unix kernel restrict access to the ports below 1024 to "root". Well known ports were allocated in this region.

If you saw an incoming connection which came from such a port you could trust it, because you knew that Dick, or John, or Jane would not allow their machine to be hacked. Likewise only trusted programs on your machine could open such ports.

Now of course you can buy a computer for about the cost of 3 pints of beer (e.g. Raspberry PI) or less this is no longer true.

So the first question from the OP was why he got back an "Invalid port" message, and that is because the daemon is objecting to port number 100, a reserved port.

The followup question in the comments is why is it objecting. The answer here is a bit more nebulous. If you ask the system to send the contents of a fifo then you can send arbitrary sequences of bytes with almost any timing. As @A.B indicates this allows you to use an FTPD as part of an attack.